# scala define SQL function to spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with SQL Spark in scala. I want to create a function that given two arrays of us any type return their union.

```
def anyarray_agg_statefunc(state: WrappedArray[Any], value: WrappedArray[Any]): WrappedArray[Any] = state ++ value

// Registers a function as a UDF so it can be used in SQL statements.
sqlContext.udf.register("anyarray_agg_statefunc", anyarray_agg_statefunc(_:WrappedArray[Any], _:WrappedArray[Any]))
```

I tested with the following code, but it gives me the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Any is not supported
```

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Any is not supported

Comment: I think I found the solution. Apparently it is necessary to record the type:

Comment: def anyarray_agg_statefunc[T](state: WrappedArray[T], value: WrappedArray[T]) = state ++ value

Comment: sqlContext.udf.register("anyarray_agg_statefunc", anyarray_agg_statefunc(_:WrappedArray[Int], _:WrappedArray[Int]))

Comment: and how you'll define the type of T?